# Is $R\subseteq S$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $T=\{\emptyset\}, Q=\{T\}, R=\{T,\emptyset\}, S=\{T,Q,R\}$

Is $R\subseteq S$

> $$R=\{T,\emptyset\}$$
>   $$R=\{\{\emptyset\},\emptyset\}$$
>   $$S=\{T,Q,R\}$$
>   $$S=\{\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\{\emptyset\},\emptyset\}\}$$

It seems to me that $R$ is indeed a subset of $S$, as R is contained inside S. Is this correct?

Comment: $R\in S$, but $R$ is not a subset of $S$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not true that $R$ is a subset of $S$, even thought it is true that $R$ is an element of $S$.

Remember, for $R$ to be a subset of $S$, it must hold that every element of $R$ is also an element of $S$. However, the empty set is an element of $R$ but it is **not** an element of $S$. (Note that $T$ is not the empty set, since $T$ has 1 element whereas the empty set has 0 elements.)

Comment: Cheers @pre-kidney!